# Let $\varepsilon >0$ exist a finite interval $[a,b]$ and a bounded function $h$ such that then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{|f(x)-h(x)|}dx<\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue integrable.
>   Let $\varepsilon >0$ exist a finite interval $[a,b]$ and a bounded function $h$ such that  $h(x)=0$ if $x\not\in[a,b]$ then
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{|f(x)-h(x)|}dx<\varepsilon.$$

---

**My attempt：**

As $f$ is Lebesgue integrable then $f<\infty$.

Let $$g_n(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if}\  x\in[a,b]\\0&\text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$

Note that $g_n\rightarrow f$, then apply the Dominate convergence theorem

$$\int_{a}^{b} g_n\,dx \to \int f\,dx$$

Here, I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: The definition of $g_n$ does not have an $n$?

Comment: This is really confusing. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: Please check again @CameronWilliams

Comment: The point is you have to specify the interval too. Try restricting $g_n$ to the interval $[-n,n]$ and let it be a truncated version of $f$ to make it bounded.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is measurable and finite almost everywhere since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable. We can find a sequence of simple functions $\{f_n\}$ with compact supports, such that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere and $|f_n|\le |f|$.

In order to satisfy the boundedness condition, we modify $f_n$ slightly:

Set $h_n=f_n\chi_{\{|f_n|\le n\}}$, then $h_n\to f$ a.e. and $|h_n|\le |f|$ but $h_n$ is bounded by $n$.

Since $f$ is integrable, dominated convergence theorem tells us that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)-h_n(x)|dx=0 .$$

By the definition of limit, for every $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a $N>0$, such that for every $n\ge N$, 
$$\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)-h(x)|dx<\varepsilon$$
where $h(x)\colon =h_N(x)$.

Note that $h(x)=h_N(x)$ has compact support, say $\{x\colon h(x)\ne 0\}\subset [a,b]$, then we have already found such a function $h$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find $[a,b]$ and $h$. Your argument does not work. Take $g_n(x)=fI_{\{x:|f(x)| \leq n\}} I_{[-n,n]}(x)$ and apply DCT. Take $h=g_n$, $a=-n$ and $b=n$ with $n$ sufficiently large.